# What webhook is called when updating user from mangopay dashboard?

Tags: php, prestashop-1.7

I am using mangopay in my prestashop project. I want that when any user update his details from mangopay dashboard, then this information should also be updated on my site. So I need a webhook who will be called when any user will be updated. Please help me. If such webhook exists or any other suggextion How can I implement this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We must look at the side of the API MangoPay to find out if this is possible. Then you can connect to the MangoPay API to do whatever you want.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for your reply. @ethercreation. But I did not find anything there. :-(

Comment: Indeed, if you do not find anything here https://docs.mangopay.com/, it is not possible.